# Set SVNs working copy to public_html on cPanel server with external repos

Tags: linux, svn, centos, repository, cpanel

When I do php programming, I tend to edit in-place on the (development) server (cpanel VPS, not local) via a text editor that has built in sFTP. I like this because there isn't 100 thinkgs you have to do to "publish" the changes, you save (via FTP) and reload the page.

I want to get the source into SVN mostly so I can track other people's edits.

I currently use tortoiseSVN on my windows machine to access hosted SVN repos (csvdude/codison) for non web projects so I'm familiar with that.  Linux SVN, not so much.

My thought here (open to other ideas) is that I want the public_html folder on the server to be the working copy (Is there a problem with this?).  People can make edits as they would via sFTP and then the working copy would be committed to the external SVN repo, possibly on a late night cron..hoping I can set it up to auto-add and commit.

So aside from thoughts on the idea, I'm curious how to set up the linux svn client to commit to external repos a la tortoiseSVN.  It seems all the tutorials I see set up a local repo.

Additionally I'm worried when I check out with public_html dir as the working copy that it will overwrite everything. (yes I have backups...)

Any input or suggestions would be awesome.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new repo on my hosted SVN service.
I manually created a public_html folder using the repo browser.

On the cPanel server:

```
cd /home/[account]/
svn checkout https://svnservice.com/my_repo/public_html
```

I set up an ignore list for directories in public_html I didn't want in the repo.

Then you can add files and directories to the repo

```
cd public_html
svn add [directory]          // adds directory for commit
svn add --force .                    // adds all new files without ignoring the ignore list
```

In hindsight, I think the import command would have done something similar, I just didn't quite understand it enough.

This is a useful command as well:

```
svn status | grep '^\!' | sed 's/! *//' | xargs -I% svn rm %    // removes files from repo that no longer exist in the working copy
```

EDIT: One thing I should mention is to make sure your .htaccess blocks access to .svn directories or it could expose source code.

Comment: @billal Really?